# How to integrate cocos2d game and game center

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-center, achievements

Im a beginner programmer and was wondering how to integrate my coco2d game and gamecenter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably not looking for making a multiplayer game but how to integrate Achievements/Leaderboards (Game Center) ...
I've answered this before on another question:
[Integrate Gamecenter in cocos2d game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278085/integrate-gamecenter-in-cocos2d-game/6290129#6290129)

;-)

Answer (score 4):

Check ray wenderlich tutorials http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-12