# implementing Game Center into cocos2d 2.1 project

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, game-center

I'm playing with Game Center and cocos2d because I want to find out how to implement Game Center into game. All I want is just displaying Leaderboards and Achievements. I have followed this tutorial [Integrate Gamecenter in cocos2d game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278085/integrate-gamecenter-in-cocos2d-game/6290129#6290129) and my Achievements works good, Game Center recognise me at the beginning and LeaderBoard cannot display my scores (I've read it take very long time, but I'm waiting like over 1 day and still nothing).

Today I upgraded my cocos2d from 1.0 to 2.1 beta because I want to support iphone 5 and I saw that Helloworld example is integrated with Game Center!

Can anyone show some sample project or tutorial how to implement Leaderboards and Achievements and recognising current player with Game Center without GKHelper, just clean Game Kit? I don't want to use GKHelper because there are to many functions and I dont need it and to be honest I don't really understand it as well.

thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cocos2d has no Game Center integration. It does nothing else but open the leaderboard and achievement views. The cocos2d template doesn't even log in the local player. This minimum Game Center example only exists to show how the view should be attached in a cocos2d app. That's the only area where Game Center and cocos2d meet paths, every other aspect about Game Center is universal, ie it applies to any app, with or without cocos2d.

For a reasonably complete Game Center integration, I wager you'll have to understand and use at least 50% of the GKHelper functions, most if you want multiplayer. And to understand those methods I recommend reading the [Game Center Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: thanks for answer and sorry for late reply. I've looked at link that you posted and WWDC videos about game center. I finally managed to make achievements, displaying banner that inform about achievements's progress and leaderboards work using just pure game center. unfortunately I have still problem with submitting scores. when I submit very first score, it is visible immediately but when I want to submit next one it takes hours. Is it normal? or it's implementation mistake?